# How to detect delete status by using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, delete-row

I would like to delete 1 of records in the list. How can I detect delete status in my code as below? I want to show delete status alert (such as successful or not) in my apps. Please help.

```
NSString *wishlistID = @"5";
                NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://api.stardomtechs.com/api/product/wishlist_delete/%@",wishlistID];
                [self.manager DELETE:url_string parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

                //HOW CAN I CHECK STATUS HERE?? IF DELETED, SHOW SUCCESSFUL MESSAGE ELSE ERROR MESSAGE
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
                }
                failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

                    UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Please try again"
                                                                                     message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                                     handler:nil];

                    [alertVC addAction:okAction];

                    [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
                }];
```

Comment: It depends on the API design actually. If the API doesn't send any response body regarding the updated list or sth. then http status code 200 is enough for the client to understand that it was a successful commucation.

Comment: I am assuming that API returns success and status code as 200 if the deletion is successful. So if error is nil that means deletion is done and you can show a message.

Comment: HI Sharad, can you share some sample code here? So that I have some basic idea, thanks!

Comment: Check the AFNetworking docs.